# How can I solve the sum with two unknowns?

Tags: plotting

I have the following code description

```
e = 1.6*10^(-19);
h = 6.59*10^(-16);
v = .53*10^6;
Δ = 0.83;
η = 0.0375;
n1 = 5*10^16;
T = (1*8.617*10^-5);
Solve[n1== 
  y/(2*π*h)*
    Sum[
      1/(1 + Exp[(Sqrt[n*2*h*v^2*y + (Δ - η)^2] - g)/T]) + 
        1/(1 + Exp[(Sqrt[n*2*h*v^2*y + (Δ + η)^2] - g)/T]), 
      {n, 0, 20}],g];
```

I want to solve it for 'g' in terms of 'y' or 'g' as a function of 'y'. Then, plot it means 'g' versus 'y'. When i run this code then an error message is appeared like 'Further out put is required'. So, i do not understand how to tackle this problem.

Comment: I can not understand what you are asking. There is not integral equation in your code nor is a function `g`. Please clarify your intent.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please,re-open my question and help me to solve it.

Comment: Solve is meant primarily for polynomial and simple transcendental equations.  I tried running your code, but it quickly used all 8 GB of memory and saturated the disk transfer on my computer, so I terminated it.  The usual way to plot such equations is with `ContourPlot`, as in the answer below.

Comment: Dear bbgodfrey, your described code method take long time to give out put. how can resolve this issue? Please, help me.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that the `Sum` is meant to approximate the integral referenced in the Question.  If so, there are three variables, `{w, y, g}`.  `Plot3D` can be used to show the relationship among them all.

```
Plot3D[w[y] h, {y, 0, 10}, {g, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {"y", "g", "w"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

[image]

However, if `g` vs. `y` for fixed values of `w` is desired, `ContourPlot` can be used.

**Edit Based on Additional Information**

The question has been modified to a request to solve `w[y] == n1`.  For the benefit of those who did not see the earlier version,

```
w[y_] := y/(2*π*h)*Sum[
         1/(1 + Exp[(Sqrt[n*2*h*v^2*y + (Δ - η)^2] - g)/T]) + 
         1/(1 + Exp[(Sqrt[n*2*h*v^2*y + (Δ + η)^2] - g)/T]), {n, 0, 20}]
```

A typical term in the `Sum` is

```
(* 1/(1 + E^(11605. (-g + Sqrt[0.628056 + 0.000370226 n y]))) + 
   1/(1 + E^(11605. (-g + Sqrt[0.752556 + 0.000370226 n y]))) *)
```

Consequently, the magnitude of the term changes abruptly, when `n y` reaches the point that the `Sqrt[...]` exceeds `g`, as is evident in the requested plot.

```
ContourPlot[w[y] == n1, {y, 0, 250}, {g, 0.79, 0.86}, FrameLabel -> {"y", "g"}, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12], PlotPoints -> 400, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

A blowup shows that the curve has the expected `20` saw-tooth pattern.

[image]